# Facebook request open group member count graph v2.5

Tags: php, facebook-graph-api

I'm trying to build a basic php script to eventually get the group member count of an open Facebook group. I'm new to the sdk, but thought how hard can it be. Well untill now I'm unable to get stuff running. Could someone point me in the right direction?

The current code I have:

```
<?php 

require_once __DIR__ . '/Facebook/autoload.php';

define('FB_APP_ACCESS_TOKEN', 'AppTokenFromTool');

define('FB_APP_ID', 'AppID'); 

define('FB_APP_SECRET', 'AppSecret');

$fb = new Facebook\Facebook(array(
    'app_id' => FB_APP_ID,
    'app_secret' => FB_APP_SECRET,
    'default_graph_version' => 'v2.5' 
));

$fb->setDefaultAccessToken(FB_APP_ACCESS_TOKEN);

$request = new Facebook\FacebookRequest($session, 'GET', '/1487942378167579/members', array('summary' => 'true'));

$response = $request->execute();
$graphObject = $response->getGraphObject();

echo $graphObject;

?>
```

I actually only need the group count, not even the member data
This code errors from the point $request->execute(); I did a search on the sdk 5.0.0 and this also couldn't be found.